# Send email when Firebase database gets new data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to NodeJS and Cloud Functions for Firebase, and my website (built in ReactJS) is connected to the Firebase Realtime Database - when customer orders a product all the data he writes in html inputs become stored in my Firebase database.

Now I want to automatically send email containing that data.

From: test@mail.com
Subject: New order for you

Name: "Bla bla"
Product: "Blaa"

you get the point.

I suppose Cloud Functions for Firebase is the answer, could someone help me? What code should I implement in functions/index.js?

EDIT: This is the JSON data from my database:

```
{
  "Email_Message" : {
    "-LOOFLA-OFkKY_6Ut03b" : {
      "email" : "",
      "message" : "",
      "name" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this official sample from the "Cloud Functions for Firebase Sample Library": https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/email-confirmation

In this sample, the Cloud Function is triggered each time a new node is written (and modified) under the `/users` main node. You should adapt this path to your own data structure.

Also note that the event handler that is used in the sample is `onWrite()`, "which triggers when data is created, updated, or deleted in the Realtime Database". If you want to trigger the email sending only when an order is created, you may use the `onCreate()` handler, see the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

---

**Update, based on your update with the database structure.**

Based on your structure you should adapt the Cloud Function sample code as follows:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// Configure the email transport using the default SMTP transport and a GMail account.
// For other types of transports such as Sendgrid see https://nodemailer.com/transports/
// TODO: Configure the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google Cloud environment variables.
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/Email_Message/{mailId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  const snapshot = change.after;
  const val = snapshot.val();

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"......" <youremail@xxxxxxxxx.com>',
    to: val.email,
  };

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'Dear ' + val.name;  //for example
  mailOptions.text = val.message;

  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('email sent to:', val.email);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
  }
  return null;
});
```

Comment: could you be more specific? i already tried to implement that example, but as i said i am new to nodeJs and firebase cloud functions

Comment: How would you like me to be more specific?? ;-) The sample code is rather simple and you just need to adapt it to your database structure. If you update your question with your database structure I can indicate how to modify the "triggering path". If you encounter difficulties with the Project Setup and Cloud Functions deployment, I would suggest you look at this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#0

Comment: This is the path to my database https://swordsmith-vladimir-cervenka.firebaseio.com/Email_Message

Email_Message is object with 3 strings: name, email, message

Could you give me some suggestion about how to implement it in the example code you mentioned?

Comment: What I need is the structure of your database (not the path). You can open the Firebase console, then go to the Database part, choose Realtime Database, click on the button with 3 vertical dots in the upper right corner and select "Export JSON". Add the JSON (or a meaningful part of it) to your original question. Thx

Comment: post edited :) thx for patience

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: No, it didn`t work, i set my email, hardcoded email & password, everything and still it wont work, here is the error i got when tried to deploy it: 

  18:106  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with ESLint, see https://eslint.org/docs/about/. You should carefully check the syntax of your code.