# Firebase Real-time alert email notification when user submit data Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase rule how to get an email notification to my own email when user submit data[Firebase rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VDM8.jpg).
From firebase rules side..
mail notification sent coding not done in the app

Comment: What is the error here? What query are you trying to run?

Comment: if someone submit data in the app. can i receive a mail notification to my email

Comment: What is the problem with the shared rules?

Comment: There is no problem. Only want to get an email notification to my email when an user submit data from android. From firebase rules side.

Comment: sorry this is not well explained, so I can not help you. Can you explain the issue in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trigger sending an email from Firebase security rules.

If you want to send an email when data is entered into the database, consider using a solution like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that can be [triggered on such a database write operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_function). A similar (not same) scenario is shown in the example on [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Also see:

- [Send email when Firebase database gets new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720954/send-email-when-firebase-database-gets-new-data)
- [I want connect my firebase information with my mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363501/i-want-connect-my-firebase-information-with-my-mail)
- [Send data from Realtime Database using Firebase Functions to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573507/send-data-from-realtime-database-using-firebase-functions-to-email)
- [Sending automated emails from Firebase through Google Cloud Platform (no third parties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616809/sending-automated-emails-from-firebase-through-google-cloud-platform-no-third-p)

Comment: Use all steps change app password but no mail received.

Comment: I answered your question on whether you can send an email from security rules, and explained how you **can** implement that use-case instead. If you're having trouble making that work, I recommend posting a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).